# Renaming the default 'Root' key in a plist

Tags: ios, plist

I have created a plist called Questions. When I created the plist it automatically created a key called 'Root'. How I can rename it to 'Questions'?

Here's what's I've written in the .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Questions" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.questions = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Questions"]; //mine is called root not    questions?

    NSDictionary *firstQuestion = [self.questions objectAtIndex:0];
    self.lblQuestionTitle.text = [firstQuestion objectForKey:@"QuestionTitle"];
    self.lblAnswerA.text = [firstQuestion objectForKey:@"A"];
    self.lblAnswerB.text = [firstQuestion objectForKey:@"B"];

   if([firstQuestion objectForKey:@"C"]){

      self.lblAnswerC.hidden = NO;
      self.btnC.hidden = NO;
      self.lblAnswerC.text =[firstQuestion objectForKey:@"C"];

    }

     else{
      self.lblAnswerC.hidden = YES;
       self.btnC.hidden = YES;

        }

     if([firstQuestion objectForKey:@"D"]){

      self.lblAnswerD.hidden = NO;
      self.btnD.hidden = NO;
      self.lblAnswerD.text =[firstQuestion objectForKey:@"D"];

     }

      else{
      self.lblAnswerD.hidden = YES;
      self.btnD.hidden = YES;

     }


}
```

---

Here's my plist - I'm am using the plist to create a simple quiz - I am storing my questions and answers here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>QuestionTitle</key>
    <string>What is sum of 1 + 1?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>D</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
    <string>B</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>QuestionTitle</key>
    <string>When to wear ear defenders?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>85db</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>88db</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>100db</string>
    <key>D</key>
    <string>70bd</string>
    <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
    <string>A</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>QuestionTitle</key>
    <string>When a child cries in loud noise you should?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>Ignore</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>Smile</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>Move Away from sound</string>
    <key>D</key>
    <string>Get annoyed</string>
    <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
    <string>C</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>QuestionTitle</key>
    <string>1+3 =?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>7</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>D</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
    <string>D</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>QuestionTitle</key>
    <string>5 + 5 =?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>7</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>10</string>
    <key>D</key>
    <string>15</string>
    <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
    <string>C</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Please show the plist.

Comment: You needn't to rename this. What do you want with this plist ?

Answer (score 4):

`Root` is just an identifier shown in Xcode which represents the base container in the plist. The key `Root` is never actually added to the plist itself (unless you add another `Root` key). The `Root` is usually an array or dictionary and doesn't actually have a key of its own.

---

Put another way, `Questions` wouldn't exist in your plist either. `questions` would be the name of the variable that you load the plist contents into...

You should just have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *questions;

self.questions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: What a huge waste of time and resources this question is.  +1 though, I guess :)